# how to make language button switch on laravel

Tags: laravel, button

i'm using blade template, all file content is in view and i need 2 language on my project, how the easiest way to make the button switcher language? can someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

You can create language links like:

```
<a href="{{ route('locale.setting', 'en') }}">
  EN
</a>
<a href="{{ route('locale.setting', 'es') }}">
  ES
</a>
```

You will need a route that will change the current language:

```
Route::get('set-locale/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);
    session()->put('locale', $locale);
    return redirect()->back();
})->middleware('check.locale')->name('locale.setting');
```

And a middleware that will set the appropriate language for other routes:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(session()->has('locale')) {
            app()->setLocale(session('locale'));
            app()->setLocale(config('app.locale'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: I took over an old project with a Laravel 5.8 installation and they cannot update. I followed the steps, added the Middleware in the Kernel.php and it also runs into the class and "tries" to set the locale. But whatever I do, the default language is always the one that shows up. Their default is "de" and if I set it to "en" it translates. But I can not set the value for some reason. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel comes with localization support. Its explained in depth [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/localization).

What you basically need to do is to define all your localization strings inside the `resources/lang` directory. By default you'll find an `en` directory where there are files that hold localization for different parts of the application. You can create an `app.php` file inside the `en` folder and define keywords and their English text. Then add another folder for your language (for example `es` for Spanish) and also create another `app.php` in there with the Spanish texts. These will be your translation strings.

These strings can be used in your views using the `__` function or `@lang` blade directive.

To change the current language (locale), you need to setup a route that listens for this request and set the locale accordingly. Something like this:

**`routes/web.php`**

```php
Route::get('/setLang?lang={locale}', function ($locale) {
  \App::setLocale($locale);
  // Session::put('locale', $locale); // This should also work

  return back();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

that's alot of work... You should use language files, like en.php and use `define()` to store translations. Note that de variable should be the same across all files. Example:

```
en.php
define('GREETINGS', 'Hello');
```

Now in portuguese for example:

```
pt.php
define('GREETINGS', 'Olá');
```

Now, in your language selector or master switch, you should store in a session variable like `user_language = 'en`. On every request / page load, define the proper file to load translations.

EDIT #1 - To be clean, use a middleware to handle this.

I think you got the idea!

Comment: Why use define when laravel recomend to return array of `key => value`  and use key with different translation functions like `trans` and `__`